# Enabling console login on CentOS

Tags: centos, security, login, console

I've inherited a CentOS system where I can't login via the console. I can ssh to the machine and login, but not via the console.

How do I go about enabling console logins?

Comment: What do you mean, you can't?  What do you see at the console (graphical faceplate / good old tty login prompt / something else), what do you do, and what happens when you do it?

Comment: What have you tried with what results ? Assuming that by the console you mean the GUI, did you try enabling the iKVM via integrated Baseboard Management Controller  (BMC) via ipmitool ? Or the Console Redirection (SOL) ?

Comment: This is VM (using ESXi 5.1). When I connect to the console via vCenter, I'm unable to login. This was apparently desired by the prior admin. It appears that console was removed from /etc/securetty and root was the only account configured.

Comment: The /etc/securetty issue appear to not be the only thing preventing this.